# tomcat7 virtual directory mapping

Tags: struts2, tomcat7

I have followed this blog: [A programmer's blog](http://harkiran-howtos.blogspot.ie/2009/08/map-external-directory-into-your.html). All upload images go to

**Z:\glass_server_upload** and I added a file named **ImageView#img.xml** in the tomcat **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\Catalina\localhost**. And the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="Z:/glass_server_upload" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" path="/ImageView/img" debug="9"></Context>
```

And now I want to display the images, so I enter the browser like this: **localhost:8080/ImageView/img/pulpit.jpg**.
But the result is sadly 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the post the file should be

```
<Context docBase="Z:/glass_server_upload">
</Context>
```

What do you need to do:

1. Locate `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost`
2. Create a textfile there named `ImageView#img.xml` with the contents above
3. Start/restart Tomcat
4. Enter in the browser via `http://localhost:8080/ImageView/img/yourimage.jpg`
5. if the file exists and you have permission to read the file, then it will be shown.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I post it here.